# Example of using Redux with vanilla, controlled form components in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux, but not to React. And I'm having trouble envisioning how to architect this.

My app has a complex, nested data structure—a "record." A single-page form lets users edit all the fields for that record. Edits are not simple: I need to check whether certain fields are different between the old record and any new edits, upon the user's submission of the form. If there are differences, I need to perform a bunch of fancy logic to update the record properly. (For example, edits the user made to a single field may need to be propagated to various deep parts of the record, a list of derived data needs to be re-generated and stored in the record, etc. etc.)

I want to:

- Use Redux as the record store. (I got this part.)
- Hydrate my form component with a single record from the store.
- Use vanilla React to store form field state (i.e. ordinary controlled form elements)
- On submit, compare the old record (i.e. from the store) with the new record (my component's state), perform fancy logic, and then update the store with the record.
- I don't want to install other libraries, besides Redux or Immutability Helper. So, no Redux-Forms or other business.

What's the best way to architect this? I have the *basic* architecture down. That is, I have got a Redux store working and can do simple updates (like pushing new data to an array, or replacing an entire record). But I don't know how to organize my "fancy logic" and *where* to do the fancy logic I need. For example, should this logic:

- Be handled by my form component, before dispatching a neat object to be stored in the Redux store?
- Be in an external utility library, and called by the action creator?
- ...be in an external utility library, and called in the reducer?
- ...be handled directly in the action creator or reducer, all dozens of lines of logic?

Thankful in advance for pointers to examples of mixing plain vanilla React forms with Redux, and tips on how to architect this.

Answer (score 0):

My ["Practical Redux" tutorial series](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux/) has three posts that cover exactly this kind of behavior:

- [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/)
- [Practical Redux, Part 7: Form Change Handling, Data Editing, and Feature Reducers](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/)
- [Practical Redux, Part 8: Form Draft Data Management](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-8-form-draft-data-management/)

The approach I demonstrate is to copy the item being edited to a "draft data" section of the Redux store, have all form change updates apply to that draft version, and then have reducer logic to overwrite the original version with the changes when the user saves the updated form.  You could certainly have variations on that if you want, including keeping the draft data in component state instead.

In general, I personally would try to move most of the actual logic outside of the components, as most of that should be independent of the components themselves.  Jack Franklin has a recent article on [extracting logic from React components](https://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2017/07/react-extracting-logic/) that's a good example of that mindset.

Also, note that you may want to consider [using selector functions to derive data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html), rather than explicitly putting it all in the store.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your example project has a lot of idiomatic code because you're using Redux-ORM, etc. I frankly need simpler, more vanilla examples. The tutorial is wonderfully rich, though: Good work on it all!

Comment: The basic principles and structuring should apply either way - it's just a question of how you've chosen to implement the actual data management logic, and what abstractions you're using.